# How do I sign a file using SSH and verify it using a certificate authority?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, digital-signature, cryptography

I would like to give a selected number of developers ability to run code on a system, and verify it using OpenSSH's `-Y verify` feature.

```bash
# Generate the certificates, and sign the dev cert with the root CA
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Example Root CA" -N "" -f ./rootca
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Some Developer Inc." -N "" -f ./developer
ssh-keygen -s ./rootca -I somedeveloper@example.com ./developer.pub  # <- Creates ./developer-cert.pub

# Sign "example.bin"
echo "hello" > ./example.bin
ssh-keygen -Y sign -f ./developer -n "codesign@example.com" ./example.bin
```

Now, Given "example.bin", "example.bin.sig", "rootca.pub", and "developer-cert.pub", how would you be able to verify it?

The `ssh-keygen -Y verify` command takes no parameter for the "developer-cert.pub" file, which is critical for completing the trust chain between the CA and the signature.

I could use `ssh-keygen -L`, but it seems insecure (Who actually *checks* the root CA signature in the certificate?).

It seems my only option is to use libssh currently, is there another way?

EDIT: Thanks to the answer by @user1686 I have completed the example:

```bash
# Generate the certificates
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Example Root CA" -N "" -f ./rootca
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "Some Developer Inc." -N "" -f ./developer

# Sign the dev cert with the root CA, granting a "codesign+foo" entitlement
ssh-keygen -s ./rootca -I somedeveloper@example.com -n codesign+foo@example.com ./developer.pub  # <- Creates ./developer-cert.pub

# Sign "example.bin" using the "codesign@example.com" namespace (doesn't grant any entitlements, just used for security)
echo "hello" > example.bin
ssh-keygen -Y sign -f ./developer-cert.pub -n "codesign@example.com" ./example.bin

# Verifying the "codesign+foo@example.com" entitlement
echo "codesign+foo@example.com cert-authority $(cat rootca.pub)" > allowed_signers.conf
ssh-keygen -Y verify -I "codesign+foo@example.com" -n "codesign@example.com" -s example.bin.sig -f allowed_signers.conf < example.bin
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must specify the certificate *when creating the signature,* so that it will be embedded in the signature's `public_key` field instead of the plain pubkey. (When signing, ssh-keygen will automatically find the nearby private key when given `-f developer-cert.pub` but not the other way around.)

Later when verifying, the signature will be verified against the public key embedded within, and the public key will be checked against the "allowed signers" file (where your CA can be specified using `cert-authority`).

(The OpenSSH certificate format doesn't support intermediate CAs, so there is no option to embed or specify the "certificate chain" like in X.509, and the term "root CA" doesn't mean much.)